# How to view a Custom Object's List Views without having a Tab

Tags: list-view

I don't have any more Tabs available.  How do I view an Object's List Views even though I don't have a Tab for the Custom Object?

Comment: Did you want to make this a wiki question and answer?

Comment: Yup.  This is also to promote the Salesforce Idea.  Seems like it'd be easy as pie for Salesforce to put this info on the Object Detail page.

Comment: Then please mark the question as a Wiki so it is filed in the proper place :) Only you or a moderator can do it

Answer (score 4):

To access a Custom Object's List Views without having a Tab for the Custom Object, you need the Custom Object's **Key Prefix**.  If you have the Key Prefix, you can use the following link:

`https://[salesforce domain]/[keyPrefix]`

### Example:

Key Prefix: `a0t`

List Views:  `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/a0t`

### How to get a Custom Object's Key Prefix:

If you can navigate to a record for the Custom Object, say through a Related List, take the first 3 characters of the record's Id -- that's the **Key Prefix** for the Custom Object.

*Example:  Record Id = `a0g1a000001Eyg1` implies the Record's Object's Key Prefix = `a0g`*.

Another way is to get the Custom Object's Key Prefix via Apex.

*Example:  Use the following in Execute Anonymous:

`System.debug('keyPrefix: ' + My_Object__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());`*

Please up-vote my Idea to add the Key Prefix to Custom Object's Detail Page for quick reference.  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DxNVAA0

Comment: In some cases, you don't need to know the key prefix. For example, you could create a custom button in a Visualforce page and use something like: `{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.List, null)}`. You can use this syntax anywhere formulas are available, including most types of custom buttons, Visualforce pages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a visualforce page to display the id and name of the objects then got the 3 digit prefix from the id field. then just like mentioned above you can take the salesforce url and add the 3 digit prefix to the end. You can also cheat your way to a few other shortcuts with the 3 digit prefix.

> `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/a0t/e'

will take you straight to creating new for the object

After this you can create shortcut links to get there quicker. Once I know what the prefix is I like to add the 3 digit prefix to the description field of my custom objects so I can find it easier later

Comment: Yea, I ended up doing the same